# How to query MongoDB via Spark for geospatial queries

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

Is there any way to use MongoDB with Spark for geospatial queries? I cannot see how to do that with Stratio.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to query geospatial data from spark. Use magellan https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan or hive esri geospatial toolkit. https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop 
I've never tried the mongo librairie from stratio, but with the spark data source api, or the mongo connector, I think you can run geo queries with the mongo syntax then convert them into an RDD or a Dataframe.

Comment: Magellan cannot do proximity queries at the moment. Esri sounds interesting tho.

Answer (score -1):

You can query MongoDB from Spark SQL using this [library](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB). 
MongoDB allows applications to do the following types of query on geospatial data: inclusion, intersection, proximity.

Obviously, you will be able to use all the other operator in addition to the geospatial ones. Let's now look at some concrete examples.

Here is an example:
Find all the airports in California. For this you need to get the California location (Polygon) and use the command $geoWithin in the query. From the shell it will look like :

```
use geo
var cal = db.states.findOne(  {code : "CA"}  );

db.airports.find( 
  { 
    loc : { $geoWithin : { $geometry : cal.loc } } 
  },
  { name : 1 , type : 1, code : 1, _id: 0 } 
);
```

The Result:

{ "name" : "Modesto City - County", "type" : "", "code" : "MOD" }
...
{ "name" : "San Francisco Intl", "type" : "International", "code" : "SFO" }
{ "name" : "San Jose International", "type" : "International", "code" : "SJC" }

If you would like to try other example, check out this blog post [here](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2014/08/introduction-to-mongodb-geospatial.html).

Comment: how do you get to run proximity queries with stratio?